# Php Function To fetch all columns

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day All,
I have written a function to show a certain image from my table if the given time does match my table records. The following is my function:

```
public function image_rank_per_hour($minhour)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM phpvms_ranks 
                        ORDER BY minhours ASC";
            $result = DB::get_results($sql);
            $hours = floor($minhour / 3600);
            if(intval($hours) >= 0 AND intval($hours) < 5)
                {
                    return $result[0]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 5 AND intval($hours) < 10)
                {
                    return $result[1]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 10 AND intval($hours) < 35)
                {
                    return $result[2]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 35 AND intval($hours) < 95)
                {
                    return $result[3]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 95 AND intval($hours) < 170)
                {
                    return $result[4]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 170 AND intval($hours) < 300)
                {
                    return $result[5]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 300 AND intval($hours) < 1000)
                {
                    return $result[6]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 1000 AND intval($hours) < 5000)
                {
                    return $result[7]->rankimage;
                }
            if(intval($hours) >= 5000)
                {
                    return $result[8]->rankimage;
                }

        }
```

It does what I'm trying to achieve since my table is static and will not change but I want to be able to fetch other columns as well. ($result[0]->rank)

Thanks

Comment: is there any problem if you `$result[0]->rank` ?

Comment: That way I only get {$result[0]->rank}. I want them both.

Comment: are you want to return `$result` whole array ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear on what you want here, but possible solution.

```
public function image_rank_per_hour($minHour)
  {
    $queryData = getData();
    $result = searchResults($queryData, $minHour);

    // You now have the result object for the given range.
    // and can return the entire thing, or whatever part 
    // of it you need for example:
    // return $result;
    // return $result->rankImage;
    // return $result->rank;
    return ['rank' => $result->rank, 'image' => $result->rankImage];
  }

  protected function getData()
  {
    // Side note, it is more efficient to name your columns instead of just using *.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM phpvms_ranks 
      ORDER BY minhours ASC";
    return DB::get_results($sql);
  }

  protected function searchResults($data, $minHour)
  {
    // potentially could be defined at class level
    $rangeResource = [
      ['key' => 0, 'min' => 0,'max' => 5],
      ['key' => 1, 'min' => 5, 'max' => 10],
      ['key' => 2, 'min' => 10, 'max' => 35],
      ['key' => 3, 'min' => 35, 'max' => 95],
      ['key' => 4, 'min' => 95, 'max' => 170],
      ['key' => 5, 'min' => 170, 'max' => 300],
      ['key' => 6, 'min' => 300, 'max' => 1000],
      ['key' => 7, 'min' => 1000, 'max' => 5000],
      ['key' => 8, 'min' => 5000, 'max' => null],
    ];
    // Get formatted hours to check against.
    $hours = getHours($minHour);

    // Iterate over resource to find matching hour range.
    $result = null;
    foreach ($rangeResource as $range) {
      // If not in range go to next iteration.
      if (!checkRange($hours, $range['min'], $range['max'])) {
        continue;
      }
      // Set result and end loop.
      $result = $data[$range['key']];
      break;
    }

    return $result;
  }

  protected function getHours($minHour)
  {
    $hours = floor($minhour / 3600);
    return intval($hours);
  }

  protected function checkRange($value, $min, $max = null)
  {
    if (!empty($max)) {
      return ($value >= $min && $value < $max);
    }
    return ($value >= $min);
  }
```

Comment: It gives me the following error on line 29 and 43 which is an open bracket.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home1/msflight/public_html/pilots/phpvms/core/common/PilotListData.class.php on line 43

Comment: What version of php are you using? if it is before 5.4 you would have to change the bracket notation to array(); notation. 

I just went back through and checked, I'm not seeing any missed semicolons or closing brackets but I may be overlooking something.